# CakePHP validator rules in UsersTable.php wont work

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm creating a change password form in CakePHP, which requires that a user enter his/her current password, new password, and confirm new password. After all that is entered, the user's password will be changed, given that all entries follow the validation rules that are set.

However, the validation rules aren't working. The user doesn't have to fill in all of the fields, set the new password to a certain length, make sure that the new password and confirm password fields match, etc. I cant seem to find out what the problem is.

I'll provide all of the relevant code below. Thanks :)

**change_password.ctp (The view file)**

```
<div class="users form large-9 medium-9 columns">
    <?= $this->form->create() ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend> <?= __('Change Password') ?> </legend>
        <?= $this->Form->input('current_password', ['type' => 'password']) ?>
        <?= $this->Form->input('new_password', ['type' => 'password']) ?>
        <?= $this->Form->input('confirm_new_password', ['type' => 'password']) ?>
    </fieldset>

    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Save')) ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
```

**changePassword() in UsersController**

```
public function changePassword()
{
    $user = $this->Users->get($this->Auth->user('id'));
    if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
        $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, [
                'password'      => $this->request->data['new_password'],
            ],
            ['validate' => 'password']
        );
        if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
            $this->Flash->success('The password is successfully changed');
            $this->redirect('/users');
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error('There was an error during the save!');
        }
    }
    $this->set('user', $user);
}
```

**validationPassword() in UsersTable (i.e The validation rules)**

```
public function validationPassword(Validator $validator )
{
    $validator
        ->add('current_password','custom',[
            'rule'=>  function($value, $context){
                $user = $this->get($context['data']['id']);
                if ($user) {
                    if ((new DefaultPasswordHasher)->check($value, $user->password)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            },
            'message'=>'Incorrect Password!',
        ])
        ->notEmpty('current_password');

    $validator
        ->add('new_password', [
            'length' => [
                'rule' => ['minLength', 6],
                'message' => 'The password must be at least 6 characters!',
            ]
        ])
        ->add('new_password',[
            'match'=>[
                'rule'=> ['compareWith','confirm_new_password'],
                'message'=>'The passwords does not match!',
            ]
        ])
        ->notEmpty('new_password');
    $validator
        ->add('confirm_new_password', [
            'length' => [
                'rule' => ['minLength', 6],
                'message' => 'The password must be at least 6 characters!',
            ]
        ])
        ->add('confirm_new_password',[
            'match'=>[
                'rule'=> ['compareWith','new_password'],
                'message'=>'The passwords does not match!',
            ]
        ])
        ->notEmpty('confirm_new_password');

    return $validator;
}
```

**EDIT: Added User.php file**

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Entity;

use Cake\ORM\Entity;
use Cake\Auth\DefaultPasswordHasher;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

/**
 * User Entity.
 *
 * @property int $id
 * @property string $first_name
 * @property string $last_name
 * @property string $email
 * @property string $username
 * @property string $password
 */
class User extends Entity
{

    /**
     * Fields that can be mass assigned using newEntity() or patchEntity().
     *
     * Note that when '*' is set to true, this allows all unspecified fields to
     * be mass assigned. For security purposes, it is advised to set '*' to false
     * (or remove it), and explicitly make individual fields accessible as needed.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_accessible = [
        '*' => true,
        'id' => false,
    ];

    /**
     * Fields that are excluded from JSON an array versions of the entity.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_hidden = [
        'password'
    ];

    protected function _setPassword($value) {
        $hasher = new DefaultPasswordHasher();
        return $hasher->hash($value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have validation rules for fields `current_password`, `new_password` and `confirm_new_password` but you are only setting the field password with `patchEntity` that's why this validators are not called.

```
 public function changePassword()
{
    ...
    $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, [
            'password'      => $this->request->data['new_password'], // There is no validator defined for the field 'password'
        ],
        ['validate' => 'password']
    );
    ...
}
```

In your case you must change your code with

```
public function changePassword()
{
    ...
    $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, [
            'password'      => $this->request->data['new_password'], // Your actual field in db
            'current_password'  => $this->request->data['current_password'], // Trigger validation rule current_password
            'new_password'  => $this->request->data['new_password'], // Trigger validation rule new_password
            'confirm_new_password'  => $this->request->data['new_password'], // Trigger validation rule confirm_new_password
        ],
        ['validate' => 'password']
    );
    ...
}
```

In  the  view file you have also forgot to pass the entity as first  parameter of `Form::create()`

Comment: My User table has a column for password, which holds the user's password. The other fields are there for validation, but wont actually be inserted in to the User table. So, if I did add the code to set the other fields, I wouldnt be able to insert into my DB.

Comment: I tried doing what you recommended, and it gives me an error. Because I dont have the corresponding tables for new_password, current_password, and confirm_new_password

Comment: Did you mean *the corresponding fields* ? Validation rules are applied in the patchEntity function, not before. I've updated my answer

Comment: Yes. Im using MySQL for my DB, and my User's table doesnt have new_password, current_password, and confirm_new_password fields. I just have one field for password. I also tried what you last updated and it just doesn't make a difference.

Comment: This code is working on my side, so I need more info to help you. Can you also provide the User entity code ?  Also add debug($user) statement after the patchEntity() and check the output, errors field should be populate. Also make sure that the validatePassword() function is properly called with a debug() statement. Finally you must add the requirePresence() rules for all password fields. The notEmpty rule is not enough.

Comment: Ok, it working. But theres only one problem left. The error messages from validationPassword() won't show if the validation rules aren't met.

Comment: Thats because you forgot to pass the user entity un form::create()